# Is it possible to store a user input answer in java into a database?

Tags: java, database

```
Is it possible to ask a user for his phone number in java such as 
import java.util.Scanner; 
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = scan.next();
int i = scan.nextInt();
```

and then add his response to a database in MS Acess or MySQL.

Comment: *Is it possible to store a user input answer in java into a database?* Yes **it is** possible.

Comment: An easy way to self-answer such questions, in the positive-case: *Has anyone else (that I know, through experience using other products or by learned knowledge) done "this" before*?

Comment: Look here for an example/tutorial: https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-statement

Comment: Storing in DB doesn't depend on *where* this data you wanna store is coming from

Comment: Try researching and using different database libraries for Java

Comment: ***Of course*** it is possible. How do you think IT systems work exactly?

Comment: Thank You very much, I am just begging to learn code and was wondering if such thing was possible for my first project.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish is absolutely possible.  There are however several steps that you will have to take to make it possible.
I am going on the assumption that you will be using MySQL for this.  MSAccess while a great desktop application is not the best tool for this.

First things first.  If you don't already have MySQL installed I would suggest doing that first.  Instructions can be found here : [My SQL Community Server](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

Once you get MySQL up and running you will need a connector for your Java application.  In this case, I would suggest [Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-binary-installation.html)
You can install these many different ways depending on if you are using Maven, Ant, etc.  So You will need to follow the directions matching your setup.

One point to note out.  From your `public static void main(String[] args)` DO NOT put in `import com.mysql.jdbc.*` this will cause a lot of issues for you.

Ok before we get into saving your information you need to verify a few things.

1. Make sure that MySQL is configured to allow external TCP/IP
   connections.
2. Make sure within your project that you have the connector installed and the CLASSPATH set up.

From there its all straight forward with some SQL code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

Connection conn = null;

try {
    conn =
       DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=youruser&password=yourpassword");

    // you code goes here to save the data you wanted

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    // handle any errors
    System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
    System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
}
```

This will get you started.  More details to move forward can be found here:
[Connecting to MySQL Using the JDBC DriverManager Interface](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)

Comment: Thank You for taking the time to answer, I will definitely Check everything out and will look more into research to get my program started